# SELECT inside INSERT query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to insert the user id from table users inside table session , field  session_user, using textbox , but it seems it doesn't work ..

Here is my SQL code, I am using visual studio and trying to insert to a SQL Server table

```
SqlCommand addsession = new SqlCommand
  ("insert into dbo.session(session_user) 
    values (select user_id from dbo.users where username = '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", 
   badersql);
```

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: And you **SHOULD** by all means use a **parametrized** query instead of concatenating together your INSERT statement......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `VALUES` keyword when you're doing an `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
insert into dbo.session (session_user) select user_id from dbo.users ...
```

Comment: SqlCommand addsession = new SqlCommand(" insert into dbo.session (session_user) select user_id from dbo.users where username = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", badersql); , i tried to do this but it gave me this error " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'session_user'."

Answer (score 4):

If you are inserting the result of a query into another table, just leave out the `VALUES` keyword.

The `VALUES` keyword can *always* be replaced by a simple `SELECT 'dummy', 'value'` of the values you want to insert, but I suggest you still use `VALUES` whenever you want to make it clear that your results do *not* come from a query.

That being said, *please* use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)!! Imagine if someone were to enter the following text into TextBox1:

`' or 1 = 1`

What would happen?

Comment: thanks for the tip , but this project is  will be locally on my computer and it won't be used in the internet now or in the future, i know parametrized queries are the correct thing to do , but no need to use them right now , thanks again

Answer (score 2):

To insert records from a query use this insert syntax:

```
insert into dbo.session (session_user) 
select user_id from dbo.users where username = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'
```

You may want to do a `select top 1 userid` if you are expecting one row to be inserted like in the values statement.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

i did it , the problem was that i can not name my record session_user , so i replaced with se_user and that solve the problem .

thank u all for ur help

so the correct sql statement is

```
insert into sessions (se_user) select USER_ID from users where username = '';
```